# How to split the data returned in jQuery autocomplete between two different HTML elements

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need some help with jQuery autocomplete.

Basically, I would like to split each set of data returned between two HTML elements. Here is my working code that returns the entire data only in one element:

```
var autocomp    =   jQuery.noConflict();
    autocomp(document).ready(function() {
        var aTags = ["ask<####>1","always<####>2", "all<####>3", "alright<####>4", "one<####>5", "foo<####>6", "blackberry<####>7", "tweet<####>8","force<####>9", "westerners<####>10", "sport<####>11"];

      autocomp('#category').autocomplete({
            source: aTags,
            open: function (e, ui) {
        var acData = autocomp(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
        acData
        .menu
        .element
        .find('li')
        .each(function () {
            var me = autocomp(this);
            var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
            me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b>$1</b>'));
        });
    }
        });
    });
```

The HTML:

```
<div>
     <input type='text' name="category" id="category" >
</div>

<p class="a">You selected id: <span id="results"></span></p>
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to display only the first part (before the `<####>`) in `category` and the second part in `results`.

So I would like to get:

```
category value = 'ask'
results value = '1'
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bradg/t0m27967/5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to change the aTags array in the format of array of object. This can be accomplished automatically, if you need.

The snippet:

```js
var autocomp = jQuery.noConflict();
autocomp(document).ready(function() {
  var aTags = ["ask<####>1","always<####>2", "all<####>3", "alright<####>4", "one<####>5", "foo<####>6", "blackberry<####>7", "tweet<####>8","force<####>9", "westerners<####>10", "sport<####>11"];
  /****
            var newATags = [{label: "ask", value: "1"}, {label: "always", value: "2"}, {label: "all", value: "3"},
                {label: "alright", value: "4"}, {label: "one", value: "5"}, {label: "foo", value: "6"},
                {label: "blackberry", value: "7"}, {label: "tweet", value: "8"}, {label: "force", value: "9"},
                {label: "westerners", value: "10"}, {label: "sport", value: "11"}];
            **/
  newATags = aTags.map(function(currentValue, index, array) {
    var retVal = {};
    retVal.label = currentValue.substr(0, currentValue.indexOf('<'));
    retVal.value = currentValue.substr(currentValue.indexOf('>') + 1);
    return retVal;
  });
  autocomp('#category').autocomplete({
    source: newATags,
    select: function(e, ui) {
      var tmp = ui.item.label;
      ui.item.label = ui.item.value;
      ui.item.value = tmp;
      autocomp('#results').text(ui.item.label);
    },
    open: function (e, ui) {
      var acData = autocomp(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
      acData.menu.element.find('li').each(function () {
        var me = autocomp(this);
        var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
        me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b>$1</b>'));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
    <input type='text' name="category" id="category" >
</div>

<p class="a">You selected id: <span id="results"></span></p>
```

Comment: thank you for the input. I tired a similar solution in the beginning but had to change it since the `bold` effect on the matching user input was being lost. Any idea if the `bold` effect can be applied to your code as well? My JSFiddle was updated to reproduce the effecti am talking about.

Comment: Thanks, mate! This is exactly what I needed!